# Function process diagram of cut polygon tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, tools, documentation

As far as the Cut Polygon tool from the Editor toolbar is concerned, polygons can be cut into two or more shapes according to that line drawn by a user.

Where can I get a detailed function process diagram of that tool, or any other tool or command of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: What is a function process diagram? Can you give an example of one to give us a better idea of what you're after.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. The Esri documentation is available [online](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-a-polygon.htm). If the diagram you're looking for isn't present there, it's unlikely to be available anywhere.

Comment: Process diagram means... Detailed flow diagram of function or in other words process behind the function..  Vince .. yeah that documentation is a result. I want actual process happening behind the screen